# how light works traffic simulation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a light for traffic simulation system
I'm writing a light class which is represents a traffic signal like this

- period, i.e. the number of time steps between two changes from green
  to red
- green-period, i.e. the number of time steps where the signal is
  green.
  Like this pic:[it shows how the light works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4zDj.png)

so I wrote this

```
class Light:
    """Represents a traffic light"""

    def __init__(self, period, green_period):
        self.period = period
        self.green_period = green_period
        self.color = 'G'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color

    def __repr__(self):
        pass

    def step(self):
        time = 0
        while True:
            time += 1
            if time < self.green_period:
                self.color = 'G'
            else:
                self.color = 'R'
            if time == self.green_period:
                break

    def is_green(self):
        if self.color == 'G':
            return True
        elif self.color == 'R':
            return False


def demo_light():
    """Demonstrats the Light class"""
    a_light = Light(7, 3)

    for i in range(15):
        print(i, a_light, a_light.is_green())
        a_light.step()

def main():
    """Demonstrates the classes"""
    print('\nLight demonstration\n')
    demo_light()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm trying to get this

```
0 (G) True
1 (G) True
2 (G) True
3 (R) False
4 (R) False
5 (R) False
6 (R) False
7 (G) True
8 (G) True
9 (G) True
10 (R) False  
11 (R) False
12 (R) False
13 (R) False
14 (G) True
```

but the result is:

```
0 G True
1 R False
2 R False
3 R False
4 R False
5 R False
6 R False
7 R False
8 R False
9 R False
10 R False
11 R False
12 R False
13 R False
14 R False
```

Comment: So everything seems to work properly except for the fact that once the traffic lights become Red they never come back to Green, right?

Comment: Yes that is it, I think there is something with loop in step() which I couldn't figure it out@FLAK-ZOSO

Comment: I'm thinking on it while writing the answer, hope I'll find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def step(self):
    time = 0
    while True:
        time += 1
        if time < self.green_period:
            self.color = 'G'
        else:
            self.color = 'R'
        if time == self.green_period:
            break
```

So, this is the `Light::step` function, and what we know is that the problem comes from here, since it's supposed to turn the light from green to red, but it seems to always give red.

```
a_light = Light(7, 3)
```

This is our instance of `Light`, it has a `period` of `7` and a `green_period` of `3`.

[image: ...]

The image above is how you explained it's supposed to work.

---

The problem is in the first line of the method `step`, because `time` is always set to zero, and so the value "returned" (there's no return but I think you got it) will be always the same since the only "variable" always starts from the same value.

```
def __init__(self, period, green_period):
    self.period = period
    self.green_period = green_period
    self.color = 'G'
    self.time = 0 # This variable will tell you which instant we're in
```

Now that you have `time` as a variable attribute, you can re-write the `step` function this way.

```
def step(self):
    self.time += 1
    # If time is on green phase...
    if time%self.period < self.green_period: # [For example 9%7 < 3]
        # ...then turn it to green (doesn't matter if it's already green)
        self.color = 'G'
    else: # ...else, if the time isn't on green phase it must be on red phase
        self.color = 'R'
```

This should work, I haven't tested it but I think it's very close to what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Names matter.

Your `period` identifier is perfect.

Please rename `green-period` to `green-interval`,
as it denotes a (non-recurring) length of time
that happens after a recurring periodic transition.

Authors will sometimes express this concept with
a fractional "duty cycle", but that seems inconvenient here.
Keep it in units of update time steps, that makes perfect sense.

---

There is a `for` loop within `def step`
which doesn't seem to belong there.
The caller is already looping, calling `.step()` repeatedly.
After enough calls, the light will change color, then change back again.

Rather than

```
def step(self):
    time = 0
    ...
```

consider moving it to a `self.time = 0`
assignment inside the `__init__` constructor,
so time shows state of the world rather than number of
steps into the current cycle.
Retrieve "steps into current cycle" with modulo, with `self.time % self.period`.

---

You wrote

```
if time == self.green_period:
    break
```

That is a good comparison, as far as it goes.
But it is only solves half the battle, and
it doesn't take care of some important housekeeping chores.

The `step` method needs to detect *both* transitions,
from R -> G as above, and also G -> R.

When it detects a transition, it must flip the color!
It must assign a new value to `self.color`.
That is the crux of your complaint -- `step` is not yet doing that.

---

Your `str` `self.color` representation is perfectly sensible, I can
certainly see why you initially chose it.

But given the "update" responsibility that `step` has,
you might possibly find this a more convenient representation,
using an `int` index rather than a `str`:

```
    def __init__ ...
        self.color = 0
        self.colors = 'GR'

        ...

        # advance the color to next-in-sequence
        self.color = (self.color + 1) % len(self.colors)

        # display current color
        print(self.colors[self.color])
```

One *big* motivation for this is looking ahead
to when you have a requirement for displaying three states:

```
self.colors = 'GYR'
```

Comment: Well, it took me 5 more minutes but I got the error was there. I tried to write a solution in the answer but I'm not sure if it works. But yes, the problem whas the loop inside the method which was already looping so... +1